# Can we display the sql result filled in $dataset on the ISE console or do we need a GUI?

Tags: sql, .net, powershell

I want to display sql results in powershell console

I have a query that list documents based on the customer code, I was able to output them to a CSV, but I am thinking if I could display them on the console and then do operations like Copy, delete etc.
Or do I need .net web UI to display the results?

Answer (score 0):

```
cls
$SQLserver = "YourSQLserverName"
$SQLDB = "YourDbName"
$SQLQuery = "SELECT * from [DBName].[dbo].[YourTableName]" # Whatever is your query

$Result = SQLCMD -S $SQLserver -d $SQLDB -Q $SQLQuery -s "~" -W
Write-Host "Display SQL Dataset in the console" 
Write-Output $Result # Display the dataset in console
```